# Javascript Improve code switch statement

Tags: javascript, optimization, switch-statement

I am trying to improve my code by reducing the number of repetition.

In the code here, I want to avoid this switch step, because, the different cases are the same except the comparison operators `===` and `!==`.

```
function Test(step, nb_change, name, value, previous_name){
    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
                if (name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value === 'nd') {
                    To_change(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        case 2:
            for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
                if (name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value !== 'nd') {
                    To_change(i);
                    return true;
                }
             }
             return false;
        case 3:
            for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
                if (select_name !== previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value !== 'nd') {
                    To_change(i);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        default:
            alert('ERROR');
            break;
    }
}
```

Do not hesitate to propose a solution that could help me.

This is just one case from a lot !
How can I find help to improve my code when I guess it could have been better written ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look at each body of each case. Figure out what's the same in each, and what's different. Make the similar parts the body of a function, and make the different parts parameters to the function. That's the basic method of generalizing code.

Comment: @j08691 I didn't know that was a thing, cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function that receives a parameter that describes how equality should be handled. Here we can take advantage of bitwise operations to give the desired description.

```
function Test(step, nb_change, name, value, previous_name) {
    const BOTH_EQ = 3;
    const NAME_EQ = 2;
    const NO_EQ = 0;

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
            return myFunc(BOTH_EQ, nb_change, name, previous_name, value);
        case 2:         
            return myFunc(NAME_EQ, nb_change, name, previous_name, value);
        case 3:          
            return myFunc(NO_EQ, nb_change, name, previous_name, value)
        default:
            alert('ERROR');
            break;
    }
}

function myFunc(compare, nb_change, name, previous_name, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
        const first_eq = (name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1]) << 1;
        const second_eq = value === 'nd';

        if (compare === (first_eq | second_eq)) {
            To_change(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `compare` parameter is passing named constants that describe the result of `OR`ing the first equality comparison (shifted one bit to the left) with the second equality comparison.

This works because `true` will be coerced to the number `1` and `false` to `0`. So we have four possible results:

```
true, true   == ((true << 1)  | true)  == ((1 << 1) | 1) == (0010 | 0001) == 3
true, false  == ((true << 1)  | false) == ((1 << 1) | 0) == (0010 | 0000) == 2
false, true  == ((false << 1) | true)  == ((0 << 1) | 1) == (0000 | 0001) == 1
false, false == ((false << 1) | false) == ((0 << 1) | 0) == (0000 | 0000) == 0
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe: You're right, I missed that. Will update.

Comment: Great the bitwise operations ! Your example is good, just I do not need the switch statement and I can simply use the const equality straight in place of my step variable.

Comment: @jardindeden: Yes, if you can change `step`, that's definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```js
function Test(step, nb_change, name, value, previous_name){
  var result = false;    
  for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
    var result = false;
    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        result = name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value === 'nd';
        break;
      case 2:
        result = name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value !== 'nd';
        break;
      case 3:
        result = name !== previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1] && value !== 'nd'
        break;
     default:
        alert('ERROR');
        break;
    }

    if (result) {
        To_change(i);
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test(step, nb_change, name, value, previous_name){
    var valueCheck,
        nameCheck;

    switch (step) {
        case 1:
          valueCheck = value === 'nd';
          nameCheck = name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1];
        case 2:
          valueCheck = value !== 'nd');
          nameCheck = name === previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1];
        case 3:
          valueCheck = value !== 'nd';
          nameCheck = select_name !== previous_name[nb_change-1-i][1];
        default:
            alert('ERROR');
            break;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < nb_change; i++) {
        if (nameCheck && valueCheck) {
            To_change(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```